# My dialog box component is not Showing in Reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs, react-redux, frontend

I have a component name dialog Box and i want to show it on click over all other components . I have a main component as

```
class ImageEditor extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { images: [], redirect: 'no', imageId: '', isDialogOpen: 'no' };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let promise = apiGateway.getImages();
      promise.then((images) => {
        this.setState({ images: images });
      });
}

openDialog = () =>{
  this.setState({ isDialogOpen : 'yes' });
}

closeDialog = () =>{
this.setState({ isDialogOpen: 'no' });
}


deleteImage = (id) => {
  apiGateway.removeImage(id);
}

setRedirect = (id) => {
  this.setState({ redirect: 'yes', imageId: id });
}



renderImage(image,index){

  return(
    <div key={index}>
     <p>Title: {image.title}</p>
     <p>Description: {image.description}</p>
    <button onClick={(e)=> this.deleteImage(image._id)}>DELETE</button>
    <button onClick={(e)=> this.setRedirect(image._id)}>UPDATE</button>
    <button onClick={this.openDialog}>SHARE</button>
    <img className='image' src={image.link} width='100' height='100' alt='nature'/>
    <br/><br/>
    </div>
    );
}


  render() {
        const { redirect , isDialogOpen } =  this.state;
        if(redirect === 'yes'){
          return <Redirect to={`/update/${this.state.imageId}`}/>
        }

         if(isDialogOpen === 'yes'){
          <DialogBox />  ????????
        }
    return(  
                 <div>
                      <div>{
                        this.state.images.map((image,index)=>{

                          return this.renderImage(image,index);
                        })
                      }
                      </div>
                </div>
    );
  }

}

export default ImageEditor;
```

When a person clicks on SHARE , I want Dialog Box to Open.I donot know the way i am doing i.e loading component with dialogBox is right or wrong. So every Advice or any suggestion will definitely help me. Here is my dialogue component(Right now i am getting a error as :Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions)

```
class DialogBox extends Component {

  render() {

    return(
        <div>
        <Dialog title="Dialog Title" modal={true} onClose={this.handleClose} buttons={ [{ text: "Close", onClick: () => this.handleClose() }] }>
                        <h1>Dialog Content</h1>
                        <p>More Content. Anything goes here</p>
        </Dialog>
        </div>
        );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <insert your other components>
    {this.state.isDialogOpen === 'yes' && <DialogBox />}
  <div>
)
```

I'd advise using boolean instead of string for `isDialogOpen`.

Comment: thanks for your advice. from now i will use boolean value. but that component still not loaded..where should i put this code ??

Comment: In your `ImageEditor`'s `render`, add `{this.state.isDialogOpen === 'yes' && <DialogBox />}` to in between the last 2 `</div>`.

Comment: Nothing is happening !!. i put it in between last 2 </div> also when i am clicking on SHARE button Scroll is going up. i think component is loading but not showing.. i may be wrong !!

Comment: You clicked on the "SHARE" button? Does it work if you just have `return < DialogBox />`?

Comment: Also not sure what `Dialog` component you are using. Does the `modal` prop dictate whether it's opened or closed?

Comment: if i return <DialogBox/>  inside if(isDialogBox === 'yes ') ,  the array of images that i am showing is not comming

Comment: modal tell Whether overlay is added to dialog or not, and Dialog ( import Dialog from 'react-dialog'; )

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on https://codesandbox.io/s/new?